How to setBackgroundColor as Color, not as int
How to set setBackgroundColor if I have got Color(Long) or how to get hex from Color?
enum class ColorRes(val color: Color, val resource: Int)
SIZE(Color(0xFFFF655C), R.drawable.size_icon)

.setBackgroundColor(colorRes.getColor()).  ??


if you have a long and want to get a hex, just do String.format("#%06X", YourLong)

@JustSightseeing I have enum which return Color, but I need to set this color to setBackgroundColor, which need in body ColorInt int color

I can't remember that android.graphics.Color had a constructor with single Int parameter. AFAIK, String and Int representations of hex color are convertible into a Color object. I wonder why you need to hold android platform specific class object, but however, we have a method to convert Color into Int, but it is

Added in API level 26

regarding the documentation
